# Data type of date column is showing as string in QGIS but back in CSV file it is date type

Tags: qgis, csv, date, geometry-data-type

I have created a .csvt file as name as same CSV file and placed in same directory. After that data type of date column are showing as a date type but when I am checking it in attribute table values are showing NULL.

I want date column type to be a date type after importing CSV in to QGIS.

Comment: Give an example of your .csvt file and one row from the .csv that includes a date string.

Comment: What version are you using? the csv column parser may have been modified. Your best bet would be to use the field calculator to ensure the values are properly interpretted and saving it as something else.